# How do I turn a series of IDs into corresponding URLs?

Tags: r

So I have a list of 1350 IDs from the RePEc database that look like this:

`repec_id <- c("RePEc:bep:uomlwp:umichlwps-1003", "RePEc:hal:wpaper:hal-02187883", "RePEc:hal:journl:hal-02184200")`

Each ID matches to a webpage. you get to it by removing the data before the first colon (as well as the first colon itself) then replacing the following colons with `"/"` and adding `".html"` at the end. I want to get a list of these websites. In other words, I want my output to look like this:

`links <- c("https://ideas.repec.org/p/bep/uomlwp/umichlwps-1003.html", "https://ideas.repec.org/p/hal/wpaper/hal-02187883.html", "https://ideas.repec.org/p/hal/journl/hal-02184200.html")`

Does anyone know how I do this? I'm a bit lost. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `gsub` allows you to replace one string pattern for another. So replace `RePEc:` with `https://ideas.repec.org/p/` and you'll be most of the way there... Then replace colons with slashes. And `paste0` the `.html` on at the end. You can do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
paste0("https://ideas.repec.org/p/", gsub("RePEc/", "", gsub(":", "/", repec_id)), ".html")
# [1] "https://ideas.repec.org/p/bep/uomlwp/umichlwps-1003.html"
# [2] "https://ideas.repec.org/p/hal/wpaper/hal-02187883.html"  
# [3] "https://ideas.repec.org/p/hal/journl/hal-02184200.html"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work regardless of what each repec_id starts with (before the first colon).

```r
library(stringr)

repec_id <- c("RePEc:bep:uomlwp:umichlwps-1003", "RePEc:hal:wpaper:hal-02187883", "RePEc:hal:journl:hal-02184200")


str_remove(repec_id, '^[^:]*:') %>%  #remove everything before 1st colon
  str_replace_all(pattern = ':', replacement = '/') %>% #replace colons with '/'
  paste0('https://ideas.repec.org/p/', .,'.html')       #paste everything together

#> [1] "https://ideas.repec.org/p/bep/uomlwp/umichlwps-1003.html"
#> [2] "https://ideas.repec.org/p/hal/wpaper/hal-02187883.html"  
#> [3] "https://ideas.repec.org/p/hal/journl/hal-02184200.html"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>